# What is the meaning of this syntax within the array.reduce() method?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am working through a functional javascript library and found a one-liner which takes the average of numbers in an array. I am confused by something which was included in the syntax but does not seem to be required for the result to be returned correctly.

```
const numArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0) / array.length;

Result => 5.5
```

The part that seems optional is the ", 0" at the end before the ")/".

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: `a` is the accumulator. This is the value to be added to the total. `b` is the currentValue - 0 is passed in here as a default value. Have a look at the method signature for [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Try it with and without an empty array.

Comment: Thats an optional initial value. The reason its the same is because in this case, calculating the sum of an array, if you start with zero its the same as if you start with the first value in the array.

Comment: You're right `, 0)` is optional, when it's there it used as initial value and if not the first call to reduce have 1 and 2 item in array. It would be needed if you have code like this `[{x:1},{x:2},{x:3}].reduce((a,b) => a + b.x, 0)`

Comment: @Lewis perfect thanks. thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `average` function shown can be divided into two parts, of which only the first part is relevant to answer the question.

The first part creates a sum of all the numbers inside the array:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0)
```

Indeed, the part `, 0)` at the end isn't necessary here, because `reduce` *either* awaits a starting value (here `0`) or it starts with the first element inside the array as a seed value. I personally think, adding the `, 0)` part makes it a bit clearer what the indent is: Add up all the numbers, starting from zero.

By looking at the line, there is an unnecessary grouping operator inside the reducer function. Therefor, it can be rewritten like this:

```
array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Or, if you have a `add` function (like `const add = (a, b) => a + b`):

```
array.reduce(add, 0)
```

Without a seed value, we then arrive at the shortest form:

```
array.reduce(add)
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript `array.reduce` method takes 2 parameters, first is callback function, second one is the initialValue that will passed to the callback function as first initial value if we need to pass different value, and it is `optional`. If it is not defined, the first element is used as an initial value.
For more info, look this [Javascript array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

Here `0` is the initial value or some time also know ass accumulator. So in reduce call back function the initial value of `a` argument will be set to `5`. In this demo instead of `0` , 5 is passed and check the first log. It will print `5`. So what ever you will pass that will initial value of `a`. The second log will be `initial value` + `first element in the array` that is `5+1=6`. Now the initial value will change to 6 and the third log will be `6+2=8` & so on

```js
const numArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => {
  console.log(a)
  return (a + b);
}, 5) / array.length;

console.log(average(numArr))
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, let us first understand the reducer function:

```
Arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => (/* do something with the parameters */), initialValue);
```

Here:

**accumulator**: The accumulator accumulates the callback's return values

**currentValue**: The current element being processed in the array.

**initialValue**: Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback.

The first time the callback is called, `accumulator` and `currentValue` can be one of two values. If `initialValue` is provided in the call to `reduce()`, then accumulator will be equal to `initialValue`, and `currentValue` will be equal to the first value in the array. If no `initialValue` is provided, then `accumulator` will be equal to the first value in the array, and `currentValue` will be equal to the second.

You can read more [here in the documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

[According to Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the second parameter is the initial value:

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

To answer your question: why is it required?

It is required to account for zero-length arrays and avoid exceptions. If you ommit the second parameter, should your array have zero elements, you'd get an exception, as shown below:

```js
const numArr = [];

const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b)) / array.length;

console.log(average(numArr));
```

On the other hand, if you add the initial value:

```js
const numArr = [];

const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0) / array.length;

console.log(average(numArr));
```

In this case you've got a `NaN` because in the end you'd have `0 / 0`, which results in `NaN` in JavaScript. But at least you don't have any exceptions :).